# How to display HEIGHT variable FIX header panel using JSF and Primefaces?

Tags: html, jsf, layout, primefaces

I use Primefaces 6.2 `<p:layout>` to display a FIX header (that is always displayed on top of page).

But the header sometimes is to high and I need reduce it DYNAMICALLY.

I decide to replace Header panel with a toggleable panel like this

```
<p:layout id="PageLayout" fullPage="true">

    <p:layoutUnit position="north">
        <p:panel id="TitlePanel" toggleable="true" header="Title">
            <p:ajax event="toggle" update=":PageLayout"/>
        </panel>    
        ... others panels with context, status, date, time, etc ...
    </p:layoutUnit>

    <p:layoutUnit id="ContentBloc" position="center">
        ... web page with specific data
    </p:layoutUnit>

</p:layout>
```

This work well except that the position of the `ContentBloc` is never updated.

When I click on toggle Button, the content of header's panel is hidden but the vertical position of the `ContentBloc` is never changed !

I used `update` attribute in `<p:ajax>` element but this has no effect.

Question: How can I do to UPDATE ContentBloc position ?

Remark: On Chrome, if after having clicked on Toggle button, I load Developer Console, the display is immediately correct !

Remark: if in maximize my Chrome Windows the display is also correct !

Comment: Does this problem only appear in Chrome? It seems that it is purely CSS related. As the PF site points out, the layout element is deprecated: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/layout/element.xhtml If you want to just have a fixed header I would go with pure CSS. Have a look at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sticky_header) and remember you can mix the JSF tags with plain HTML tags!

Comment: Thanks for this answer: I don't know that <p:layout> is deprecated because I used code generated 4 years ago. I will try to use <div> solution with pure CSS has proposed by you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After searching a lot, I have found the following tricky solution

```
<div id="PageHeader" style="position:absolute; left:0; top:0; width:100%;"> 
    <p:panel id="TitlePanel" toggleable="true">
        <p:ajax event="toggle" oncomplete="toggleTitlePanel()"/>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <p:outputLabel value="#{pageTitle}" escape="false" style="font-size:200%;"/>
        </f:facet>
        ... others panels with context, status, date, time, etc ...
    </p:panel>
</div>

<div id="ContentPanel" style="position:fixed;
                              left:0;
                              overflow-x:auto;
                              overflow-y:auto;
                             ">
    ... web page with specific data
</div>
```

For this code to work, I have

1. added "toggle" event to position ContentPanel.
2. added some JQuery event when page is loaded

The javascript code linked to `toggle` event is the following

```
function fixHeaderHeight()
    {
    var iHeight = document.getElementById("PageHeader").offsetHeight;
    document.getElementById("ContentPanel").style.top = iHeight + "px";
    }

function toggleTitlePanel()
    {
    setTimeout(function(){ fixHeaderHeight(); }, 500);
    }
```

The `fixHeaderHeight()` function CANNOT be called direclty because size parameter has not been changed when `toggleTitlePanel()` is called. So active function is call indirectly using `setTimeout()` function.

To position correctly `ContentPanel` the first time it is displayed and when screen size is changed, mimized, maximized, I have already added some javascript code.

```
<script>
    function setContentTopPosition(div)
        {
        var iHeight = document.getElementById("PageHeader").style.height;
        div.style.top = iHeight;
        }

    function onLoadPage()
        {
        fixHeaderHeight();
        }

    function onResizeWindow()
        {
        fixHeaderHeight();
        }
</script>
```

The JQuery events are initialized just before `</body>` element in `.ready()` function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function()
        {
        onLoadPage();

        jQuery("#PageHeader").resize(function()
            {
            onResizeWindow();
            });
        });

    jQuery(window).resize(function()
        {
        onResizeWindow();
        });

</script>
```

Now, Header and Content panels are correctly displayed

1. when I display this page for the first time
2. when I change windows size
3. when I click on MINUS button to collapse Header panel
4. List item when I click pn PLUS button to expand Header panel

I hope only that this solution will be helpfull for others.

Comment: I have found some problem to this solution and I have replaced "absolute" position with "fixed" and some other CSS attributes to allow scrolling of ContentPanel.

Comment: The HEADER panel must have ABSOLUTE position to avoid that MenuItem are displayed under Button defined in CONTENT panel ! The answer has been corrected.